# "git tag -l v1.1.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}" works in shell but not subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run `git tag -l v1.1.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}` in my shell I get results, however

```
def run_command(cmd_args, number_of_retry=5,
                timeout_in_second=90, suppress_output=False):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    timer = threading.Timer(timeout_in_second, proc.kill)

    timer.start()
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    timer.cancel()

    if proc.returncode and number_of_retry >= 1:
        if not suppress_output:
            print('Command "{}" failed/timeout, retrying...'.format(
                ' '.join(cmd_args)))
        return run_command(cmd_args,
                           number_of_retry - 1,
                           timeout_in_second + 10,
                           suppress_output=suppress_output)

    return proc.returncode, out, err

return_code, out, _ = run_command(
    ['git', 'tag', '-l', "v1.1.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}"],
    number_of_retry=0,
    suppress_output=False)
```

yields no results.  Changing the pattern in my code to v1.1.[0-9][0-9] yields the results that match, as does v1.1.[0-9], so its an issue with the brackets. Anyone know how this could be?  Is there another way of saying the same expression, or at least seeing the bash subprocess run so I can verify the correct command is being run? (subprocess and threading are python modules)

Comment: BTW, try running the original bash code in your current directory after `touch v1.1.0 v1.1.00`; you'll see that it no longer outputs any tags that don't correspond with filenames in the directory where the command is run. If you didn't want that, you'd want to add more quotes, as in `git tag -l v1.1.{'[0-9]','[0-9][0-9]'}`.

Comment: Another thing you can do in bash is to run `(set -x; git tag -l v1.1.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]})` -- `set -x` turns on trace-level logging; you'll see a line of output like `+ git tag -l 'v1.1.[0-9]' 'v1.1.[0-9][0-9]'`, where the content after the `+` tells you what the shell is actually running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly-brace-and-comma syntax ("brace expansion") in `v1.1.{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}` is an instruction to your shell, not to `git`; it tells the shell to split the argument into two (after which, since they contain unquoted glob characters, the shell will by default try to expand each of those resulting arguments as a glob -- hopefully you don't actually intend that behavior, and thus won't mind it being gone), and then to pass `git` two separate arguments, one for the content on each side of the commas within the curly braces.

Absent the previously-discussed globbing, the result of this shell expansion is equivalent to the following Python code:

```
run_command(['git', 'tag', '-l', 'v1.1.[0-9]', 'v1.1.[0-9][0-9]'],
            number_of_retry=0, suppress_output=False)
```

---

If you actually *do* rely on the shell to replace `v1.1.[0-9]` with a list of entries in the current directory matching that pattern should any such entries exist, the native-Python equivalent would be more like:

```
# to behave like default bash behavior (without running ''shopt -s nullglob''):
import glob
def expandGlob(word):
    return glob.glob(word) or [word]

run_command(['git', 'tag', '-l'] + expandGlob('v1.1.[0-9]') + expandGlob('v1.1.[0-9][0-9]'),
            number_of_retry=0, suppress_output=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  the first piece of code you put gets the result I wanted.  Would you mind elaborating on "(after which, since they contain unquoted glob characters, the shell will by default try to expand each of those resulting arguments as a glob" as I dont understand this.  I dont follow why my original code isnt identical to the working change you suggested

Comment: To go back into why the original code differs: Brace expansion is *performed by the shell*. When you directly execute another program without starting a shell (as you're doing here), shell expansions (globbing, brace expansion, etc) aren't performed. And that's, generally speaking, a Good Thing -- if you're passing arbitrary data (filenames, etc) between programs, parsing of those names as shell syntax is an easy way to get security bugs.

Comment: ...as for what I meant by the language you quoted, see the comments I added on the question itself, which provides a means of demonstrating the behavior at hand.